# Ubuntu 14.04 boots on Bios on Asus EeeBook X205TA

Tags: boot, grub2, asus

Hope someone can give me fix to my problem. I purchased a Asus Eeebook X205TA to access my desktop when away. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 as single OS and completed the install without any errors showing. My problem is that when I boot the system it always falls on the bios screen. I ran boot repair disk without solving the problem.I did get a boot system log on [http://paste.ubuntu.com/10981454](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10981454/)/

Is there anyway of fixing the problem so I don't need to always run the USB live disk...

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Read line 136 onwards... Maybe creating MBR instead of GPT might help...just a guess. Also install Ubuntu in Legacy mode.